# How to join two tables permanently with SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, view

Is it possible to join two tables permanently? Where I am just going to execute once that query and then after that it can be already joined automatically even if I exit DBMS?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may want to look into creating a [view](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/create-sql-views-mysql.aspx).

A view is essentially a stored SQL statement that you can query like you would a table.

```
create view MyView as
    select TableA.Field1, TableB.Field2
    from TableA
    join TableB on TableB.ID = TableA.ID


select *
from MyView
```

Comment: after that? that's it? I am not going to update it ? or something? because I am working on a JDBC project and I don't want to keep on using the join clause everytime i look for some data

Comment: can i join/vieww more than 2 tables? since i have a table for Employee,personal information and contact information

Comment: @user962206 Yes and yes.  You can join as many tables as you want.

Comment: Also not, that you might want to create *indexes* to back up the join in the view if you're not joining on `Primary Key`

Comment: I am going to join them with the primary key. since it's the simples thing I know

Comment: You still have to pay the price of `JOIN`, for each time you consult your `VIEW`.

Answer (score 0):

If you always write to both and read from the join you can merge them into one and write and select from just that one.

```
--==[ before ]==--
insert into user (id, name) values (1, "Andreas");
insert into email (id, email) values (1, "andreas - at - wederbrand.se");

select user.id, user.name, user.email from user, email where user.id = email.id;

--==[ do the merge ]==--
create table user_with_email select user.id, user.name, user.email from user, email where user.id = email.id;

drop table user;
drop table email;

--==[ after ]==--
insert into user_with_email id, name, email values (2, "Bruce", "Bruce - at - springsteen.com");

select id, name, email from user_with_email;
```